# Weight proportions not respected in nested LinearLayout

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a code like this:

```
...
    <LinearLayout
       android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:weightSum="10">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_weight="1" /> 

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_weight="8"> 

    <TextView android:id="@+id/text2"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_weight="1" /> 

     </LinearLayout>
...
```

This code is nested in other linearlayout's which have the same weightSum and weight.
The SDK I use is 1.6 Android. I cannot figure out why the amount of space assigned to the elements with weight equal to 1 is different if I remove the `TextView` in the middle. It seems that even if the Text size (number of chars) of the `TextView` are more, the `LinearLayout`s with weight 1 got's smaller .. How is this possible?

Comment: your weightSum is 10, but adding up your weights I get 12. this will cause problems if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: Thanks for your answer..I'm sorry on my program the number was the right one. 1 8 1. But still the error is there.

Comment: And the problem is still there even if this LinearLayout is not nested and even if set the contained TextView to a fixed Width (expressed in dp) ! Can the LinearLayout really contain nothing ? I need simply to put a percentage of width there and pretend that this width remains constant.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the solution. Practically I needed to set the Layout_width of each container with the weight property to 0px.

Answer (score 0):

From what I can tell, it seems your weightSum should be 12, not 10.
First LinearLayout has weight=2, the second weight=8 and the third weight=2.

It might solve your problem!

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, weight in linear layout is not so linear.  Component with a biggest weights wins all the extra space.  For playing around with layouts I highly recommend latest IntelliJ Idea - 
even free comminity edition has android plugin with really usefull layout preview.

Comment: Ok..thanks but my layout is almost completed. Will consider this the next time.